# need to delete networkIpConfigurations using API calls

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network, nic

I have a requirement where i need to delete the newly added IP address from the NIC.
I have gone through documentation 
[here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/virtualnetwork/networkinterfaceipconfigurations) , but it only provides get and delete options. Is there any way i can remove the IP ? I tried removing Public Ip directly , but it throws arror saying that NIC is using it currently and we have to de allocate it first.

Comment: do you need to do it manually or programmatically ? you can use arm template to do that